# To be helped or what

Tags: verb-usage

I've just wanted to make a sentence then my sentence is like that

> I am an athletic person, which means probably I won't need crutches TO BE HELPED for walking in the future.

I feel like this sentence is a bit odd because of to be helped. Is this sentence correct or should I make some corrections, if so what should i write instead of **TO BE HELPED** .
Thanks for responses.

Comment: I think you can just leave out "to be helped". The purpose of crutches is understood in context.

Comment: You added your comment just as I was composing my answer saying the same. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to construct something like:

> ...I probably won't need to be helped by crutches...

It's still a bit awkward. IMHO it would be just as well to leave that out altogether. What's wrong with:

> I am an athletic person, which means I probably won't need crutches for walking in the future.

or:

> I am an athletic person, which means in the future I probably won't need crutches for walking.

(Although I'm not sure that current athleticism is a reliable predictor of future crutch-needing.)

Comment: Depending on the type of athletics being discussed, it could indeed be a reliable predictor that you are going to need crutches again.